# ARM Assembler - VCVT instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded

I am quite new to ARM and not able to understand how `vcvt.u32.f32 s0,s0` is converting `s0` register from `792.0` to `1.1098284 e-42` ?
I referred to [ARM Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/vfp-instructions/vcvt--between-floating-point-and-integer-) and found this instruction is converting `s0` register from single-precision floating point value to unsigned 32-bit integer
To understand the conversion, i referred to [Tutorial_Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrlQpzc61Vc&t=6s) and found `792.0 = 0x8846_0000` in memory, which implies `2286288896` in integer
so can anyone help to understand how we are getting `1.1098284 e-42` ?

Comment: 1.1098284E-42 is what you get when you interpret the bits of 792 (an integer) as a float.

Comment: Hi @harold , if we consider its bits, then Sign =0 , Exponent = 0 & Mantissa = 00000000000001100011000 => (-1)^0 * 2^(0-127) *(1 + 2^-14 + 2^-15 + 2^-19 + 2^-20) = 1 * 2^-127 * 1.00009441375732421875 = 5.8780 e-39 ; so am i missing something?

Comment: Looks like you did not take into account that it's subnormal, so the exponent is 2^-126 and there is no implicit leading 1

Comment: Try it on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html - it has a nice visual display of the exponent and mantissa bits, and the values they represent which get multiplied together, including "2^-126 (denormalized)" when that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you wanted

```
vcvt.f32.u32  s0, s0
```

To convert from an integer to a float. It reads as `vcvt.[dest_type].[source_type]  dest, source`. However it also looks like 792 converts to 0x44460000 as a float.